# Get fanpage accesstoken with Facebook SDK v5 for PHP

Tags: php, facebook

How to obtain access token fanpage ?
I use Facebook SDK for PHP Version

```
   $fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => '{app_id}',
  'app_secret' => '{app_secret}',
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.4',
  ]);
$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
$permissions = ['email',
  'user_location',
  'publish_actions',
  'public_profile','user_posts','manage_pages','publish_pages']; // optional
$loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl('call-back.php', $permissions);
```

call-back.php 
When i use /{fanpage_id}?fields=id,name,category,access_token

```
$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
 $rb = $fb->get("/{fanpage_id}?  fields=id,name,category,access_token",$accessToken);
```

Results returned only show id,name,category
{"id":"ddd","name":"dsa","category":"ddd"}' and it can not obtain access token.

When i use /me/accounts
Results returns empty {"data":[]}'

Please help me get access token for fanpage .
Thanks

Comment: Where are you sending the user to the login URL? Did they actually get asked for permission to manage their pages in the login dialog, and grant it?

Comment: The answer to your question is here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/access-tokens